# How to compute the IUIPC score

Tags: likert

I am designing my first user study. To assess the privacy concerns of the participants I am using the [10-point IUIPC scale](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7307/1a056403ed5f9fd5b16b9dd70a93e9a4e375.pdf).
I am a little bit confused how to actually compute the score for each participant. Here is what I did:

1. Discretize the (categorical) data (Strongly Agree =5 ... Strongly Disagree = 1)
2. Compute the sum of all Collection, Control, and Awareness questions (by adding the corresponding answers – i.e., control = 5+3+4; collection = 4+4+4+4; awareness = 2+3+3)
3. Compute the weighted IUIPC sum (i.e., (control *0.78) + (awareness * 0.91) + (collection * 0.75 -- (5+3+4)*0.78 + (4+4+4+4)*0.91 + (2+3+3)*0.75).

However, I am not quite sure if this is correct. Sadly, I did not find any source that says how to exactly compute the score.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you suggest is based on a fundamental misunderstanding of psychometrics (and it is VERY common...and is a tad counter-intuitive from how people think about using multiple items to measure a single construct...so know that you have lots of fellow compatriots who struggle through this, too).

The measurement model reports the correlations of the latent (unobserved) variable with the manifest items.  In this case, you have a 2nd order measurement.  So, you are using manifest items (the survey items) to "measure" the three sub-constructs.  These sub-constructs are then used to "measure" the 2nd-order construct (IUIPC).  The problem is that we are trying to use the things we can see to estimate the things we can't see.  Unfortunately, the models (and the output reported in the paper) reports the causal process in the other direction.  The thing we can't see is determining the things we can see.  So, the values you have in your third bullet above are using the correlations between the unobserved constructs.  These aren't the values you would use to estimate what is called the factor score.  Said another way, the correlation captures the influence of the latent factors on the things we can see; but the factor scores are our estimates of the thing we can't see based on the information we actually can see.

Most likely, what you will need to do is actually run your own factor analytic model on the data you've collected.  From this, you can estimate the factor scores for your sample.  Happy to share more if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Could you explain how I can `run my own factor analytic model` on my data?

Comment: plz let me know what software package you would use to run a confirmatory factor analysis